# Format database insert in android way

Tags: android, sql

I have a database insert sql statement that does it's job.

```
String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + TABLE_USER
                + "(" + KEY_ID + ", " + KEY_EMAIL + ", " + KEY_FIRST_NAME + ", " + KEY_LAST_NAME + ", " + KEY_AVATAR + ", " + KEY_AVATAR_UID + ") "
                + "VALUES ("
                + 1 + ",'" + userInfo.getEmail() + "','" + userInfo.getName() + "','" + userInfo.getLastName() + "','" + userInfo.getAvatar() + "',"
                + "(SELECT " + KEY_AVATAR_UID + " FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + 1 + "));";


database.execSQL(sql);
database.close();
```

I want to update all fields of the user with id 1 but keep the avatar uid.
How can I write this cleaner or how can I improve this statement?

Thanks.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/about.html

Comment: Use `database.update()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the SELECT statement.

INSERT OR REPLACE will try the INSERT first.
If it fails (existing record), it will do the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the native way of Android!

```
ContentValues mValues = new ContentValues();
mValues.put(YOUR_COLUMN, YOUR_VALUE);


YOUR_SQLITEDATABASE_OBJECT.update(your_table,mValues, YOUR_QUERY, YOUR_QUERY_PARAMS);
```

Where YOUR_QUERY: ex. `"Time = ?"`

Where YOUR_QUERY_PARAMS: ex `new String[]{"9-11"}`

Answer (score 0):

At first, detect you whether you need update or insert.

Than write insert or update request.